# how to cast the integer to integer[]

Tags: postgresql

I have table like below

```
id   name    address
=====================
{1}   A        abc
{2}   B        abcd
{3}   c        abcde
```

now i want retrieve the info based on id ...
but am passing the id is integer its existing id is integer[] so how can i casting here

my query like this

```
select name,address from business where id='{1}';
```

in where clause it taking only integer[] ..but i want pass the input integer only
so please tell me how to cast integer[] to integer tell me please

Answer (score 2):

you cannot to cast integer as array, but you can create single field array:

```
postgres=# SELECT '{10}'::int[] = ARRAY[10];
 ?column? 
----------
  t
(1 row)
```

But you can use a test if value is in array (what is preferable solution)

```
postgres=# SELECT 10 = ANY('{10,20,30}'::int[]); 
 ?column? 
----------
 t
(1 row)
```